# PHP Operator strange behavior

Tags: php

===

```
echo var_dump( ! end($lines)['id'] === $r['line_id'] );
```

outputs:

```
bool(false)
```

==

```
echo var_dump( ! end($lines)['id'] == $r['line_id'] );
```

outputs:

```
bool(true)
```

but....

```
echo var_dump( end($lines)['id'] === $r['line_id'] );
echo var_dump( end($lines)['id'] == $r['line_id'] );
```

both output:

```
bool(false)
```

Why?  Should the first two examples be the exact same?

Note:  In this example end($lines)['id'] doesn't exist and $r['line_id'] is: string(1) "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `===` comparator is used, it compares **data type** and **value**. Since the same expression albeit using the `==` comparator (comparing only **value**) evaluates to `bool(true)`, we can assume these variables are the same *value*, but not the same *type*. For more information, see [PHP: Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

In the second example, you're not using the `!` operator to negate the `end($lines)['id']` reference, which doesn't yield equivalency in your case.

---

In your case, an unset variable will evaluate to a `FALSE` boolean, and the set `$r['line_id']` will evaluate to a `TRUE` boolean. Thus, `!FALSE == TRUE`. For more information on this aspect of PHP, please refer to [PHP: PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), specifically column `boolean: if($x)` column of table **Comparisons of $x with PHP functions**.

In the same fashion, the expression `! end($lines)['id'] === $r['line_id']` will yield `bool(false)` as `end($lines)['id']` does not have a datatype, and `$r['line_id']` is a `string(1)`. As such the datatypes do not match for the `===` comparator to return `bool(true)`.

Comment: Yh same here. Cant provide an answer to this question

Comment: Apologies I made  a quick edit and added what the variables were shortly after posting.  You can see them at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @Cggart I've updated my answer to reflect your most recent edit.